# Diagnosing transactional exceptions in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

Working with Spring Data Neo4j (using simple mapping mode), I occasionally come across `NotInTransactionException`'s being thrown inside methods that are annotated with `@Transactional`, and have found myself pulling out more hairs than I can afford to lose trying to diagnose these exceptions. For example, the following method:

```
@Service 
public class FooService { 
  @Autowired Neo4jTemplate template;

  //GraphPersisted is an interface containing a single method: Long getId()
  //ModelNode is an empty interface implemented by my @NodeEntity classes 

  @Transactional
  public <T extends ModelNode> T getNode(GraphPersisted g, Class<T> clazz){          
    return template.repositoryFor(clazz).findOne(g.getId()); //NotInTransactionException!!
  }
}
```

is throwing the following:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: nested exception is org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(Neo4jExceptionTranslator.java:51)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.translateExceptionIfPossible(Neo4jTemplate.java:447)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.getNode(Neo4jTemplate.java:481)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.NodeGraphRepositoryImpl.getById(NodeGraphRepositoryImpl.java:33)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.NodeGraphRepositoryImpl.getById(NodeGraphRepositoryImpl.java:24)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.findOne(AbstractGraphRepository.java:127)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.findOne(AbstractGraphRepository.java:51)
at net.mypkg.myapp.core.FooService.getNode(FooService.java:28)
at net.mypkg.myapp.citizenry.BarService.getCitNode(BarService.java:136)
at net.mypkg.myapp.citizenry.BarService.loadCitizens(BarService.java:81)
at net.mypkg.myapp.citizenry.BarService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$792b7a4e.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:640)
at net.mypkg.myapp.citizenry.BarService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$59949515.loadCitizens(<generated>)
at net.mypkg.myapp.creator.builders.VotingActivityBuilder.makeVotesFor(VotingActivityBuilder.java:46)
at net.mypkg.myapp.creator.builders.VotingActivityBuilder.build(VotingActivityBuilder.java:35)
at net.mypkg.myapp.creator.builders.VotingActivityBuilder$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6871225a.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:640)
at net.mypkg.myapp.creator.builders.VotingActivityBuilder$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f5827a1.build(<generated>)
at net.mypkg.myapp.creator.Creator.create(Creator.java:33)
at net.mypkg.myapp.creator.CreatorDriver.run(CreatorDriver.java:52)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.runCommandLineRunners(SpringApplication.java:634)
... 5 more
```

My most immediate question is: **Why is this exception being thrown?** Why is my `@Transactional` annotation not doing what I expect it to do (namely wrapping my call to `template.findOne(Long id)` in a transaction)?

My larger question is: **How do you know?** What clues are given in the stack trace that might indicate from whence the unexpected behavior is arising? I'm relatively new to Spring and Spring Data, and I'm sure these issues aren't inherently difficult to diagnose, I'm just struggling to do so because I don't know how to interpret the stack trace: What should I be looking for in the trace to diagnose these problems when they arise?

(Please let me know what further code/config is necessary to answer this question and I'll post it - I've purposely included as little as possible, in hopes that what *you* need to see to diagnose this specific issue will help me understand what *I* need to be looking at to diagnose similar exceptions in the future. I will say, though, that `@Transactional` annotations are working as expected for a large number of other methods in the same application context)

Comment: Hard to tell, but for me your `FooService` seems not to be proxied (unlike `BarService` or `VotingActivityBuilder`) thus can't be decorated with tx functionality. Might be way off, though. Tried to reproduce a similar stacktrace but couldn't; probably due to a different Spring version. What's yours?

Comment: @Hille: Interesting. Are you deducing this from the fact that there are calls to `MethodProxy.invoke()` related to `BarService` and `VotingActivityBuilder` methods but not to `FooService` methods? Could you expound a bit on what that's telling me diagnostically? PS I'm using SDN version 3.1.2 (latest stable release), which depends on Spring Data version 1.4.3

Comment: Exactly, I looked at the stacktrace and saw no "invokes" related to `FooService`. The other way to tell is to look at the stacktrace from top to bottom: You run over a `FooService.getNode` without hitting any proxy.

Comment: Did any of the answers shed some light to your question? Anything still unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap some thoughts up in an answer: Spring (any recent version) establishes transactions by instantiating proxies for objects containing a method annotated with "@Transactional". These proxies (wrapping the original functionality with enter- / exit-code handling a transaction) are generated in one of two ways:

1) via CGLIB by dynamically generating Java byte code for the subclass of the proxy target overriding the annotated method, using an instance of this subclass plus using an instance of the original class

2) via Java Dynamic Proxies mimicing the targeted class by dynamically generating an object implementing all the interfaces of the proxy target plus using an instance of the original class

Spring tries to go with 2) unless explicitly otherwise told. As 2) doesn't work if the target class doesn't implement any interfaces option 1) has to be chosen. Falling back to option 1) may break, too. Think about final methods (as Maarten mentioned) or method with a stricter scope than `public`.

These general things are all documented in the Spring reference (look for "cglib", "proxy", "transaction", ...).

Coming back to your example (hoping its not accidentally oversimplified):

a) the class `FooService` containing the annoted method `getNode` does not implement any interface (by the way this is really a bad practice; you ought to program against an interface, e.g. easily allowing you to exchange the implementation), Spring has to go the "CGLIB way". Using CGLIB should work, as nothing is `final`, the annotated method is `public`, calling the base class constructor twice doesn't do any harm, ...

b) calling from the stacktrace we can tell that the classes `BarService` and `VotingActivityBuilder` are proxied using CGLIB, so generally this does work.

c) if the mentioned `BarService` and `VotingActivityBuilder` are proxied because of an `@Transactional` annotation, you've successfully setup an transaction manager and enabled annotation driven transactions (via `<tx:annotation-driven/>` or `@EnableTransactionManagement`). Though I fear these two objects are proxied for other reasons (tell us! :-)). In the latter case instantiate a transaction manager and enable annotation driven transactions (cf. Maarten's answer).

d) lets exclude the case of multiple tx managers (you only have one, don't you?)

e) looking at the stacktrace we can exclude the case of *internally* calling `setNode` (i.e. calling it from another, not tx aware method of `FooService`). Doing so would bypass the proxied version of the annotated method.

f) last thing I can imagine for now (but can't tell from the stacktrace or your provided code for sure), is your code having more than one ApplicationContext (e.g. Web-Apps usually have a "root context" as well as a "dispatcher context" having a parent-child relation). If you instantiate `FooService` as part of a parent context and put `@EnableTransactionManagement` at your child context, then no tx logic will be generated.

I'd go for c) or f).

PS: A stacktrace of a proxied `FooService` throwing an exception in a tx annotated method `setNode` looks on my machine like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This is for testing purposes.
  at eu.example.service.FooService.getNode(FooService.java:94)
  at eu.example.service.FooService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$837ba2c0.invoke(<generated>)
  at o.s.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
  at o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
  at o.s.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
  at o.s.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
  at o.s.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
  at o.s.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
  at o.s.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
  at o.s.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
  at eu.example.service.FooService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$e1fb8939.getNode(<generated>)
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer. I was planning on holding out and putting this one up for bounty, hoping to attract exactly the level of thought you put into this answer, but have no need now. Keep up the good work, @Hille!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the stacktrace, an instance of `BarService` is making a call to a non proxied instance of `FooService`. If the latter where proxies, you would see `CGLibEnhance`-ed classes in the stacktrace and -IIRC- in your case also the `TransactionInterceptor` that is responsible for starting the transaction.

Now as to why the instance is not proxied, that is hard to say. Is `@EnableTransactionManagement` missing? Is the instance not managed by Spring? Can the class not be proxied because it is final?